# Change the IP Address on iPhone by using code

Tags: ios, iphone

My app has to connect to a server which can redistribute a new IP Address for the iOS client device.
How to change the IP Address on iPhone by using code in my app? 
The app will not be published on the app store and the iOS devices may be jailbroken if necessary.
Anyone can give some suggestion on coding?

Comment: Pl mention what you have tried.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not allowed / able to do that on non-jailbroken devices.

Comment: The client devices may be jailbroken. and how to do that on jailbroken devices?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change ip address with the non-private frameworks that you are allowed to use.

You have to find a different architecture for your server-client communication if you want your app to be published on the app store.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The app will not be published on the app store and the iOS devices may be jailbroken if necessary. 
Then, how to do that by using code?

Comment: To Nikos, would you please give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingConcepts/NetworkingConcepts.pdf) : iOS is using DHCP(Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) protocol. So As per DHCP manual IP settings are not allowed by coding.

To learn more about DHCP read [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).